# Is there a configuration to control the rate of calls between a VS C# Specflow Test Case and an Appium Server

Tags: c#, selenium, appium, specflow

I am writing some c# automation for an Android App using Selenium and Appium.  While I am getting the functionality I want, the execution is quite slow.  This appears to be caused by something controlling the rate of requests being sent to the Appium Server from the VS C# code.  For example, this is a line of code that checks if a button is displayed and enabled

```
public static void CommonEditFieldIsDisplayedAndEnabled(this FeatureContext _featureContext, string p0)
{
    AndroidElement editField;
    BasePage _currentPage;
    _currentPage = (BasePage)_featureContext.Get<BasePage>("currentPage");
    if ((_currentPage != null) && (_currentPage._editPageElements != null))
    {
        if (_currentPage._editPageElements.ContainsKey(p0))
        {
            editField = _currentPage._editPageElements[p0];
            try
            {
                Assert.Multiple(() =>
                {
                    Assert.That(editField.Displayed && editField.Enabled, $"Edit Field {p0} Not Displayed and Enabled");
                });
            }
            catch (MultipleAssertException)
            {
                Assert.Fail($"Edit Field {p0} not available for input");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Assert.Fail($"Edit Field {p0} not found in Current Page Object");
        }
    } else
    {
        Assert.Fail($"Current Page or _editPageElements are null");
    }
    return;
}
```

From the Appium Log file, this code results in 2 separate calls to the Appium Server, which are resolved in 15 and 19 ms each, but for some reason these calls (and the one following which clicks the button), appear to reach the Appium server 2 seconds apart.  This leads to 34 ms of actual work but an elapsed time of 4,132 ms, very ineffective.

> 2021-12-30 **16:07:52:970** - [HTTP] --> GET
> /wd/hub/.../00000000-0000-0160-ffff-ffff000000ac/displayed
>
> 2021-12-30 16:07:52:970 - [HTTP] {}
>
> 2021-12-30 16:07:52:985 - [HTTP] <-- GET
> /wd/hub/.../00000000-0000-0160-ffff-ffff000000ac/displayed 200 15 ms -
> 14
>
> 2021-12-30 16:07:52:991 - [HTTP]
>
> 2021-12-30 **16:07:55:042** - [HTTP] --> GET
> /wd/hub/.../00000000-0000-0160-ffff-ffff000000ac/enabled
>
> 2021-12-30 16:07:55:042 - [HTTP] {}
>
> 2021-12-30 16:07:55:061 - [HTTP] <-- GET
> /wd/hub/.../00000000-0000-0160-ffff-ffff000000ac/enabled 200 19 ms -
> 14
>
> 2021-12-30 16:07:55:061 - [HTTP]
>
> 2021-12-30 **16:07:57:102** - [HTTP] --> POST
> /wd/hub/.../00000000-0000-0160-ffff-ffff000000ac/click

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the relevant C# code? That single line of code is not enough to answer your question.

Comment: Maybe try updating Selenium, the web driver, and Appium?

Comment: Is the Appium server running locally on your machine, or is it remote?

Comment: The Appium Server is running local on my machine...as is the VS and the android emulator.  I do  not think it is machine resource constrained as the interval is too consistent.

Comment: I looked at the resource consumption of the system when running...no issue with CPU resource....also eliminates the possibility of a "busy-wait".

Comment: What  about RAM usage? With Visual Studio, an Android simulator and an Appium server running locally, the time delay could be caused by swapping of RAM to hard disk (and back).